# JAXBException UnmarshallerImpl nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

While marshalling my Java code:

```
      Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
      marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
      marshaller.marshal(um, new File("temp.xml"));
```

I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at App.main(App.java:47)
```

Comment: how you are crating jaxbContext ?

Comment: @shreyanshjogi JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance (AddressDetails.class,COUNTRY.class, Details.class, Districts.class,
ObjectFactory.class);

Comment: why you require these much class give only one master class and rest of class as child means define object of that class in master class

Comment: What is the `um` variable here?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that may be possibly causing the exception:

**Possibility #1**

One of your domain objects is holding an instance of `UnmarshallerImpl`.  I would recommend not doing this.  If you feel you must then you should annotate that field/property with `@XmlTransient`.

**Possibilty #2**

As suggested by Ian Roberts comment you may be accidentally marshalling an instance of `UnmarshallerImpl` of the `um` variable is holding an instance of your `Unmarshaller`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you import some resource of com.sun.xml.internal.bind instead of javax.xml.bind